# Netgear switch required default gateway for point-to-point link

Tags: arp, layer2, layer3, point-to-point, netgear-prosafe

So, my Netgear switch died, and after factory resetting it, I noticed that I was unable to connect to it. The Netgear was configured for `192.168.0.239/24`, and I configured my windows PC to `192.168.0.240/24` with a default gateway of `192.168.0.1` (just because I assumed I had to fill the DG parameter since it is Windows).

I ran Wireshark to sniff my laptop's interface, and I noticed the only traffic was a DHCP Discover message.  I changed the default gateway to `192.168.0.239`, and then I was able to connect.

I don't understand why this is necessary. **Since both devices (the switch and my laptop) were on the same broadcast domain, then there is no need for a default gateway**. Specifically, my laptop should have sent out an ARP request when I attempted to connect to the Netgear switch via HTTP, which should have been received by the switch since it would have been broadcasted.

**My question: Am I wrong? (And this would mean my understanding of very fundamental networking is wrong?)**

Comment: Which particular switch model, software version, and configuration. It is always better to give more information when asking for help.

Comment: Don't switches just switch? I mean, end devices are blind to the existence of switches unless there's VLAN configured on one of the switch ports.

Comment: `noticed the only traffic was a DHCP Discover message` : who was sending that? Your laptop? Sounds like he static ip configuration somehow didn't "take" and by changing the go it somehow did. If you change the go back to .1 does it fail again?

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying is correct, I can't see any reason it would require a default gateway unless there is something either misconfigured or a bug.  You should not need a default gateway if you are on the same network.  Did you see anything in the ARP cache on your PC or switch before you changed the default gateway?

Answer (score -1):

You state Netgear switch however what you describe is for L3 routing.  If configured correctly the router will respond to an arp request which is broadcast onto the lan segment with the mac address of all FF's but the router will only reply with its own mac-address if the ip it finds encapsulated in the frame is configured on one of its interfaces.

If you are still telling your host device to send packets towards a different ip of 192.168.0.1 that effectively doesn't exist then it will not work.

Comment: Sorry Matt, but I don't think you understand what is going on here.  There is no "router" involved, only two layer 3+ devices (layer 7 PC, and a layer 7 switch) connected on a p2p connection.  Since I am trying to connect to 192.168.0.239's mgmt interface via HTTP, the arp request will be flooded out to the entire broadcast domain looking for the mac address of 192.168.0.239, not of the default gateway.  If the arp request was destined to an IP on a different subnet, then yes the default gateway would matter.  Therefore, the default gateway should NOT make any difference.